# Embedded structure With XORM

Tags: go, go-xorm

I'm trying to make an embedded structure with XORM support, but i keep getting weird errors like key cascading. how can i do this?

```
type Profile struct {
    PortalLanguage   string `json:"portalLanguage"`
    PortalAutoLaunch bool   `json:"portalAutoLaunch"`
    PortalDefaultApp string `json:"portalDefaultApp"`
}
type UserProfile struct {
    Id    int    `xorm:"int autoincr" json:"id"`
    Owner string `xorm:"varchar(100) notnull index pk" json:"owner"`
    Name  string `xorm:"varchar(100) notnull pk" json:"name"`

    profile      *Profile       `xorm:"jsonb" json:"profiles"`

}
```

Then How to retrieve object?

```
adapter.engine.Get(&profile)
```

and how to update the json field?

```
adapter.engine.ID(core.PK{owner, name}).Update(profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do uppercase for profile name to Profile

Comment: Can you explain more why that? with some sample